# React-Native, only Android, no firebase: objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner,

Tags: android, react-native

I'm building a React Native 0.57 app, which works fine on IOS but fails on Android with the following error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
throwOnInvalidObjectType ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8779:6
reconcileChildFibers ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9842:31
reconcileChildren ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10319:6
updateHostRoot ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10683:6
beginWork ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11360:28
performUnitOfWork ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14091:21
workLoop ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14129:41
renderRoot ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14226:15
performWorkOnRoot ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15193:17
performWork ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15090:24
performSyncWork ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15047:14
requestWork ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14925:19
scheduleWork ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14711:16
scheduleRootUpdate ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15429:15
updateContainerAtExpirationTime ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15462:28
updateContainer ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15494:4
render ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16142:20
renderApplication renderApplication.js:59:34
run AppRegistry.js:101:10
runApplication AppRegistry.js:195:26
__callFunction MessageQueue.js:349:47
<unknown> MessageQueue.js:106:26
__guard MessageQueue.js:297:10
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue MessageQueue.js:105:17
```

I searched on the Internet et SO (of course), and everybody is talking about firebase which I'm not using.

As far as I remember, with RN 0.56 all was working fine, and since the upgrade to 0.57, this error started to occur.
The workaround is to enable the debugger ... but the release is suffering the same issue.

The issue is happening in the simulator and on the real device.

As the app is working on IOS, I guess this is coming from the android project.

How can I investigate this issue?

**UPDATE**

I found out that adding `import 'core-js'` to the top of the `index.js` file of the app is avoiding the error.

This `core-js` is a dependency of many package, like `react-native` itself.

Why is this import solving the issue and why do I have to do it, especially if the iOS version works fine?

Comment: Maybe this is related? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22573